# html select option text formatting

Tags: html, html-select

I am trying to change html select option text color to red, following is the code this code is working fine on one jsp but not working on another jsp.

Could you please provide me the solution

```
<select id="selectedWorkstationId" name="selectedWorkstationId">
   <option style="color:red" value="1" selected >
    <c:out value="test1/>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to close those Option tags like this

```
<select id="selectedWorkstationId" name="selectedWorkstationId">
   <option style="color:red" value="1" selected ><c:out value="test1"/></option>

  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your browser auto-fixed the typo in your html structure in your first jsp. Perhaps closing text in your `<c:out value="test1" />` and closing the `<option>` element will solve your problem:

try this:

```
<select id="selectedWorkstationId" name="selectedWorkstationId">
    <option style="color:red" value="1" selected>
        <c:out value="test1"/>
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, i tried your suggestion but still it is not working

Comment: Can you provide more details about your html ?

Comment: Hi Ahmad, problem has been solved, the reason was if select option have single value than style will not work. if select have more than one option than only style works.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="selectedWorkstationId" name="selectedWorkstationId">
    <option style="color:red" value="1" selected>
        <c:out value="test1"/>
    </option>
</select>

option style attribute only works if option have more than one value other wise it will not work.For single value it takes style define in select like this
<select id="selectedWorkstationId" name="selectedWorkstationId" >
```